# Can I say a logarithmic difference is "log-constant"?

Tags: terminology

I have two variables which vary linearly on a log scale.  My understanding is that I can say these are "log-linear."

I'd also like to write that the difference between the lines on a loglog graph is the same across the whole domain.  In other words, I have two lines that have the same slope and a constant space between them.

I can think of two ways of saying this, but I'm not sure whether either term will be understood:

1. The difference between the two lines is log-constant.
2. The log-difference between the two lines is constant.

Are "log-difference" and "log-constant" ever used in the literature?

Specifically the difference is *not* "constant," because e.g. `0.01 - 0.001 != 0.1 - 0.01`, however the difference between their logarithms is constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the difference between the logarithms is constant then the variables differ by a constant ratio. That is probably an easier thing to explain than anything to do with log-constant or log-difference.

Comment: [quotient rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Product,_quotient,_power,_and_root): `log_b(x/y) = log_b(x) - log_b(y)`